# Formula in case statement returning zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a really weird issue with this case statement and formula where I am getting 0 for this division formula even though if I run each statement independently I get the correct number. If I delete the second selet statement and even enter the number in I still get zero. The numbers come out to 167913/1150972, if I truncate the second number to 1150 it works but if I add in the 9 I get 0 returned.

```
CASE WHEN 
        ISNULL(MAX(JC.JOB_SHIPPED_FLAG), MAX(OE10.ORD_SHIPPED_FLAG)) = 'P' AND ISNULL(MAX(JC.JOB_STATUS_FLAG), MAX(OE10.ORD_STATUS_FLAG)) = 2
            THEN (SELECT SUM(CAST(TOT_COST AS INT)) FROM CRCDATA.DBO.LA15 
                    WHERE EST_NUMB = MAX(JC.EST_NUMB) AND LA15.QTY_SLOT =1) 
                    / 
                    ((SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(FG14.ONHAND_QTY AS INT)) FROM CRCDATA.DBO.JC11 JC11
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN CRCDATA.DBO.FG14 FG14 ON JC11.FG_ITEM_NUMB = FG14.ITEM_NUMB
                            WHERE JC11.FG_ITEM_NUMB LIKE '0000000%' AND JC11.STATUS_FLAG = 'P' AND FG14.LOC <> 'rej' ) +
             (SELECT SUM(CAST(SHIPTO_FAX AS INT)) FROM CRCDATA.DBO.SH10 WHERE RECORD_TYPE = 'B' AND PROCESS_FLAG = 4 AND SH10.JOB_NUMB = A.JobNumber))


        ELSE 0 
        END [TEST]
```

Comment: are you returning an int? `167913/1150972` evals to `0.14588...` which would round down to integer 0

Comment: Is that the whole statement, or just a part of a bigger query? Which dbms? (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: @jarlh it's part of a bigger query. It's mssql as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to cast any one of the divider or dividend to FLOAT. i.e.

```
SELECT CAST(val1 AS FLOAT) / val2
```

**OR**

```
SELECT val1 / CAST(val2 AS FLOAT)
```

Comment: That worked. Usually I use money when casting does int always round down?

Comment: Yes, casting int always round down. You can check yourself by casting float values to int.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "+.0" to one of your values

For example

```
Select 5/20       Return 0 
Select 5/(20+.0)  Return 0.2500000
```